# Sliding images web tool

Tags: silverlight, flash

We are looking for a sliding image tool like the one on the following home pages:

1) http://xceed.com/index.aspx (Silverlight based)

2) http://usa.autodesk.com/ (Flash based)

Where can we purchase something similar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found by myself:

http://www.flashcomponents.net/component/highly_customizable_xml_banner_rotator.html

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not aware of a pre-packaged control that is "exactly" like that, you can make one fairly easily, and much more creatively, using Telerik's Transition control. 
[Link to Product Page](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/transition.aspx)